# Neural network + VGG very accurate on test images and google images but extremely poor on "real" images

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, image-recognition

I made a model to classify dogs and cats pictures. Model was trained with transfer learning on VGG and then on a dogs and cats dataset from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data.

I trained it on 20,000 and then tested it on the remaining 5000 images. It was very accurate at >95%. When I hand **scrape** some images from google that are ~20-200kb it works very well from what I can tell.

But when the images are larger (thousands of pixels in height/width), like from my phone, it does horrible.

Why is this happening? Is there an image processing thing that I'm missing? Or is it a learning issue? Either way, how do I fix this and make the model extendable to large images?

model:

```
def get_transfer_model(self):
        model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))  # Use VGG transfer model
        for layer in model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False    # already trained
        
        added_layers = [ 
            Flatten(),
            Dense(512, activation='relu'),
            BatchNormalization(),
            Dropout(0.5),
            Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        ]
        
        result = model.layers[-1].output # init result
        for layer in added_layers:
            result = layer(result)        # apply to result
            
        model = Model(inputs=model.inputs, outputs=result)
        opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

result calculation:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

def result(img_path, weights_path='dogs_cats.h5'):
    img = load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
    img = img_to_array(img)
    img = img.reshape(1, 224, 244, 3) # reshape to tensor with 3 color channels
    img = img.astype('float32')
    img = img - [123.68, 116.779, 103.939] # center image to trained mean

    model = load_model(weights_path)
    dog = int(model.predict(img)[0][0])
    if dog:
        return 'DOG'
    return 'CAT'
```